How to create, maintain and apply patch files to artifacts in consumed conan Packages
A Conan Package with artifacts is consumed within a git repo. Some artifacts must be patched by multiple changes.
I search for a good way to once create different Patch files and also apply them automatically.
My current idea is, the artifact can be modified after Conan install, then I can Create a Patch by the Diff Unix command and Store this and further patches within my git repo.
Within my Conan File I can add that all patches shall be Applied After Conan install.
However my issue is, the Conan Package can be updated (contain new content, can have some issues fixed what I will find out by a Release Note). Then the original artifact can change and my  patches would not apply anymore conflict free.
How to smart update then my Patch Files according to the new artifact.
I would love something like a 3way Merge. However using git commands as far I know would only be possible of I have the artifacts as committed Part of the repo.
But I just want to commit the Conan File and my patches within my repo.
Do you have any smart ideas? That would be fantastic
As stated, only know the Unix Diff and Patch command. But no mechanism to solve the conflicts good with a 3way merge

Sorry, not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Conan recipes contain patches like in https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/tree/master/recipes/zlib/all, but they are applied at package build time, not at "conan install" time. Are you using the local development flow like in https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/developing_packages/local_package_development_flow.html? It is also possible to use the repo Github issues to ask questions.
